# Utilizando o count() no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um `controller` que joga para minha `view` o total de cursos cadastrados no portal. Minha duvida fica por conta do funcionamento do método `count()`.

Por exemplo, o `output` de ambas as instruções abaixo são equivalentes:

**1) Instrução**

```
$usuario = User::find(Auth::id());
$usuario->cursos->count();
```

**2) Instrução**

```
Curso::count('id', Auth::id());
```

Minha dúvida é, na **instrução 1** estou executando um *`select fulltable`*, retornando todas as colunas da tabela e depois passando para o método `count()` realizar a contagem?

E a **instrução 2**, ela já monta um `sql` que executa o `count` diretamente no banco retornando somente o total?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Minha dúvida é, na instrução 1 estou executando um select fulltable, retornando todas as colunas da tabela e depois passando para o método count() realizar a contagem?

Nesse primeiro código é retornado **1 usuário do tipo** `User` e com o acesso ao coleção de `cursos` e depois ao método `count()` da `classe` [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections#introduction) é contado quantos itens tem nessa coleção. Na verdade aqui são 2 `SQL`, uma recuperando o usuário e a outra trazendo os cursos daquele usuário (**leitura desnecessário**). Tem um problema em vez de você acessar a relação, `cursos()` é acessado a **coleção de cursos** (*leitura, dos dados da tabela*) e isso é bem errado, não há necessidade nesse momento, quando for utilizar os dados simplesmente faça:

```
$usuario = User::find(Auth::id());
$usuario->cursos()->count();
```

continua sendo **2** `SQL`, mas, pelo menos não carrega dados desnecessários da tabela.

---

> E a instrução 2, ela já monta um sql que executa o count diretamente no banco retornando somente o total?

`SQL` é direta, somente **1** `SQL` trazendo o resultado por filtro da quantidade de cursos, em relação a 1 é direta e se torna melhor.

---

> Resumindo:

A segunda é mais otimizada e objetiva e na primeira você dá duas voltas, porque,

```
Auth::id()
```

poderia ser:

```
Auth::user()->cursos()->count();
```

já que é entendido que a contagem de cursos e pelo usuário logado (ou autenticado). Nessa linha `Auth::user()->cursos()->count();` é criado **1** `SQL` para contagem de cursos conforme usuário logado.

Comment: Compreendi, mas ao fazer assim "Auth::user()->cursos()->count();", o eloquent monta um sql de count, ou retorna todos os dados daquele usuário para posteriormente contar?

Comment: @Fabio fiz algumas edições, e a sua duvida está nela, mas, é 1 SQL que faz um filtro conforme relacionamento com a tabela usuário e conta quantos cursos esse usuário tem, seria `select count(*) from cursos where userid = 1`, entendeu?

Comment: Perfeito. Uma última coisa, consigo um dump para ver o sql?

Comment: `Auth::user()->cursos()->toSql()` por exemplo sai a SQL, fiz outras edições agora acho que ficou melhor, leia o item 1

Comment: Muito bom. Só fiquei em dúvida em uma parte, ao ver o sql, podemos observar que é um select normal. Ao encadear o count(), o select é alterado para um count a nível de banco ou essa contagem fica por conta de um método da aplicação?

Comment: @Fábio é executado a `SQL` do `count` pela chamada do método `count()`, que pode ser feita corretamente acessando o método `cursos()` nesse caso é enviado um `SQL` para o banco, diferente de `cursos` que é o que você disse na segunda parte que já é o retorno de todos os cursos daquele usuário (sendo mais custoso e ruim nesse aspecto da sua aplicação, ou seja, nesse caso), faça dois testes que é o ideal para você entender: `Auth::user()->cursos()` vai retornar um objeto builder (construção de SQL resumindo) e `Auth::user()->cursos` vai retornar uma classe collection cheia de dados.

Comment: Muito bom. Agora entendi. Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento Virgilio.